# PowerApps: Show Details from a Gallery on a Browse Screen on a third Detail Screen

Tags: powerapps

I am developing an app using PowerApps Web.  I have a browse screen (1st Screen) with general information from a SharePoint list shown in a Gallery.

I created another screen (2nd screen) where I show some details of an item selected from the gallery in the first screen using the formula: Navigate(FirstScreen, Fade, {Variable: thisItem}).

This works perfect for the 2nd screen, but now I created another screen (3rd screen) where I want to show more details (other fields) of the same item selected from the gallery on the 1st screen where the user selected the item, but so far I haven't been able to do it.

I have to do the same thing in other screens, I'm trying to show details from the item selected in the gallery on the first screen on other screens by topic.  So far I've only being able to show information from the 1st screen to the 2nd screen, but not to the rest of the screens.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways where this can be accomplished. The first is to pass the item as a variable to the third screen: just like when you navigated from the first screen to the second screen you passed the selection:

```
Navigate(SecondScreen, Fade, { Variable: ThisItem })
```

You can do the same when navigating from the second to the third screen:

```
Navigate(ThirdScreen, Fade, { Variable: Variable })
```

Notice that the name of the context variable in the second screen is `Variable` (as it was defined in the `Navigate` function, so you would use that name as the value of the variable to pass to the third screen.

Another option is to define the selection as a [global variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables), which can be accessed via multiple screens. In this case, you would replace the current OnSelect expression in your gallery with the following:

```
Set(Variable, ThisItem); Navigate(SecondScreen, Fade)
```

That makes `Variable` a global variable that can be accessed in any screen of the app, including the third one for more details.

Yet another option is not to use variables, but instead rely on the `Selected` property of the gallery to access the properties of the selected item. For example, in the second screen where you currently have `Variable.PropertyName`, you would use `GalleryName.Selected.PropertyName`. You can access controls from any screen in the app, so this expression would also work in the third screen.